# How to add the django-evolution dir to my Python Path - Ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, django-evolution

I want to install Django-Evolution, but their documention is scarce on how to do it.  My main stumbling point (I am still learning stuff in Linux) is the following line:

> Check out the Django Evolution sources, and put the checkout directory
>   into your Python Path.

How do I do that? I guess I did it once before when I installed Django, but I was just following a blow by blow set of instructions then (http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/install_django_and_build_your_first_app/).  Here is the entire quote from their FAQ file on Evolution:

> ### How do I install Django Evolution?
>
> There have not been any official releases of Django Evolution. If you
>   want to  use Django Evolution, you will need to use a subversion
>   checkout.
>
> Check out the Django Evolution sources, and put the checkout directory
>   into your Python Path.
>
> Then add 'django_evolution' to the list of installed applications for
>   the  project in which you want to use Django Evolution.

Answer (score 1):

To put a directory on your Python path, add it to the PYTHONPATH environment variable, or create that variable pointing to the checkout directory.

Comment: is there an example of how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

To add a directory to your PYTHONPATH you need to add this line into either `~/.profile`, `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/Django/Evolution/directory
```

replacing `/path/to/Django/Evolution/directory` by the absolute path of the directory containing Django-Evolution